# Mongo as an event Triggerer

Tags: mongodb, triggers, command, queue, timed

I have this feel that mongoDB could also be used a event trigger system by using mongo's server-side javascript capability.

for example

```
    db.system.js.save(
    {
        _id : "timer",
        value : function timer(interval,times,fun){ var s=new Date(); var e=new Date(); var cnt=0; while(cnt<times){ print("audit: "+cnt); eval(fun()); cnt++; s=new Date(); while(e-s < interval){e=new Date();}}};
    }
db.testcol.save({a:timer(1000,3,function(){print(Date() + "Message");})})
```

> Output =========

```
audit: 0
Sun Mar 03 2013 16:29:46 GMT+0530 (IST)Message
audit: 1
Sun Mar 03 2013 16:29:47 GMT+0530 (IST)Message
audit: 2
Sun Mar 03 2013 16:29:48 GMT+0530 (IST)Message
```

Not explored all possibilities of this, but just this thought brings in the following
1) Trigger event system with the particular collection acting as a delayed command queue.
2) Delayed/timed persistance

Any more uses of this?

Comment: **Definitely not recommendable** .. [`eval()` takes a global write lock](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) which blocks all other read & write operations to the database while the eval runs.    This isn't an event trigger, it's a database server bazooka ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MongoDB does not have triggers: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124

The way you trigger something there is not a healthy way to do it, not even sure what that will output to the collection itself, probably the object of the function or a null value.

Also I believe this will only work in the console and never in a client side program unless you use `eval` (maybe, not even sure then), and, well, I don't even need to explain why that is bad.

You could just use active record (or something similar) instead to accomplish this.

Comment: What is an _active record_?

Comment: @Sreesankar Active record is a paradigm for implementing a currently looked at set of records within a program by implementing a model to represent these records. Hmmm, a good example is ruby on rails, that uses a ORM active record by default.